# Sync Framework - overwrite local database changes

Tags: c#, sql, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm using Sync Framework to handle syncing between local and remote databases.

I've managed to get both upload and download working, but I would like to have any local changes made to a specific table be overwritten with the original remote values; a forced overwrite in a sense.

Is there any way that this can be accomplished?

Any changes made to the remote database's table are successfully syncing down to the local db's table, but in the event that a change is made locally, it must be overwritten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SyncFx syncs incrementally (syncs changes after last sync). In your case, the remote values will not be re-sent to your local if they didn't change.

you can do a dummy update on the remote rows to force them to be re-sent, but rather than doing it that way, why dont you just prevent edits on the local copy?